# in:query and in:header parameters in yaml file

Tags: java, yaml

I'm learning creating rest Api using spring boot. FOr reference I was checking some existing code where in yaml file I found two parameters mentioned below

```
name: "name"
      in: "query"
      description: "doing something"
      x-phase-dataelem: "CONF//Y/N"
      required: false
      schema:
            type: string
            maxlength:15


name: "tame"
      in: "header"
      description: "doing something something"
      x-phase-dataelem: "CONF//Y/N"
      required: true
      schema:
            type: string
            maxlength:15
```

am literally not able to understand these parameters

```
in: "query"
in: "header"
x-phase-dataelem: "CONF//Y/N"
```

I know that, these are some values which are being passed to client url to process, but not able to understand these parameters. what's significance of using these 3 parameters ?

can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This YAML snippet looks like a Swagger/OpenAPI contract. You can find more about OpenAPi and read its specification here - https://swagger.io/specification/

`in` describes the location of the HTTP parameter.

Quote from the OpenAPI specification:

> There are four possible parameter locations  specified by the ***in***
> field:
>
> - path - Used together with Path Templating, where the parameter value is actually part of the operation's URL. This does not include
>   the host or base path of the API. For example, in /items/{itemId}, the
>   path parameter is itemId.
> - query - Parameters that are appended to the URL. For example, in /items?id=###, the query parameter is id.
> - header - Custom headers that are expected as part of the request. Note that RFC7230 states header names are case insensitive.
> - cookie - Used to pass a specific cookie value to the API.

---

Regarding the `x-phase-dataelem`, it is a custom extension in your OpenAPI contract. It is used for providing some additional metadata/information/properties about the described items (including parameters).

Quote from the OpenAPI specification:

> While the OpenAPI Specification tries to accommodate most use cases,
> additional data can be added to extend the specification at certain
> points.
> The extensions properties are implemented as patterned fields that are always prefixed by `x-`, for example, `x-internal-id`. The value can be null, a primitive, an array or an object. Can have any valid JSON format value.